# Mean of a binomial distribution

Tags: statistics

During an election, a proportion $p$ of voters choose candidate $A$, while a proportion $1-p$ choose candidate $B$. A number of $n$ voters have been polled before the election. Let $X_i$ be $1$ or $0$ according to whether or not the $i$th person will vote for $A$. The random variables are independent. What is the expected value $E[\bar X_n]$ and variance $\sigma^2_{\bar X_n}$? where  $$\bar X_n = \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$$ Use $\bar X_n$ as an estimator for $p$. Based on the Chebyshev inequality, find the smallest value of $n$ such that $$P(|\bar X_n - p|<= 0.2) >= 0.9$$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: "The mean is the sum of indicator variables 1...n over n". Sorry? Could you explain? The formula now added for the mean bar-X_n has no indicator variables in it...

Comment: @Did : Edited :)

Comment: Do mean to say here that the $X_{i}$ are i.i.d. and Bernoulli-distributed?
(In that case $X=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$ is binomially distributed.)

Comment: "Edited", yes, *unfortunately*, since the edited version explains nothing (and does not answer the questions in the comments).

Comment: Come on, Artemisia... Do something about it! People are getting unpatient here. I am the living proof of that and there is a good chance that I am not the only one :-) .

Comment: @Did : Yes of course. I thought that goes without saying.

Comment: @drhab : is it fine now?

Comment: Lapse of time between a viable version of the question appearing on the page and an answer being accepted: 5 mins. Is this reasonable? (And now the OP is mentioning an addendum... OP: You are doing your best to convince readers that this question should be closed, you know?)

Comment: @Did: all final edits have been made. I actually forgot to put in some details in the previous version. Sorry about that.

Comment: You mishandle the site and seem to be deliberately deaf about what people tell you about it. These are unfortunate choices.

Comment: @Did: I just wanted to know the variance and the mean, which was answered. How is it a mishandling? I added the second part so that if someone wishes to solve the question further out of interest, they can do so. I have already got my answer :)

Comment: "How is it a mishandling?" Are you serious? Are you even interested? I doubt both.

Comment: Interested in what? I wanted to know the answer to verify my answer for an exam I had and that's all. I have received the answer. That's all I needed. Define mishandling of the site. This is not a homework problem and I haven't asked anyone to solve the entire question for me. I don't intend to be rude, but I really don't get what you mean.

Comment: "Interested in what?" Right, that says it all.

Comment: @Did : I still don't get what you mean. I know the process, I wanted a verification to an answer. That is all. Your comments seem to be extremely irrelevant at this point. Sorry about that. If you could clarify what you mean, I can avoid the mistakes in the future.

Comment: Listen, you can repeat that you do not understand and that you did everything right, this will not change the fact that (1) you mishandle the site, and (2) you probably know it perfectly well. If really you are interested in the matter (which I doubt), every explanation is already on the page. Hence, last comment from me. (Note that to ask for *clarifications* about comments one just declared *extremely irrelevant* is an interesting piece of sophistry.)

Comment: That helps. I shall avoid it in the future. And just to clarify, I am interested in the matter... else I wouldn't ask the question in the first place. Again, I don't intend to be rude. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are iid with Bernoulli distribution.

Then $S_{n}=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$ is binomially distributed with parameters
$p:=P\left\{ X_{1}=1\right\} $ and $n$.

Here $\bar{X}_{n}=\frac{1}{n}S_{n}$
wich makes it easy to find:

$E\left[\bar{X}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n}E\left[S_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n}\times np=p$

and:

$\text{Var}\left(\bar{X}_{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\text{Var}\left(S_{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\times np\left(1-p\right)=\frac{p\left(1-p\right)}{n}$.

**Edit**

The fact that $S_{n}$ is binomially distributed is not of real importance
here. We can also directly conclude that:

$E\left[\bar{X}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n}\left(E\left[X_{1}\right]+\cdots+E\left[X_{n}\right]\right)=\frac{1}{n}\left(p+\cdots+p\right)=p$

and:

$\text{Var}\left(\bar{X}_{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\text{Var}\left(X_{1}\right)+\cdots+\text{Var}\left(X_{n}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(p\left(1-p\right)+\cdots+p\left(1-p\right)\right)=\frac{p\left(1-p\right)}{n}$

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry for the prior confusions. There is an addendum to the question... I will add that now.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer, showing that 'binomial' is not of essential importance here.

Comment: I am sure that you mean well :-) but it is not very sensible to put an addendum to the question after accepting an answer. By doing so it seems that you accepted an incomplete answer and the person who answered can feel manipulated to make his answer complete.

Comment: I understand, haha :) but the addendum is not really relevant to the previous part so I just thought of adding it. I am not sure what the other user intends in his comments- A bit too vague for my comfort.

Comment: I can assure you that @Did is of very high level! However, a consequence is that his demands - when it concerns questions - are high. I wouldn't say too high and I am speaking from an experience that is very short. Advice: keep him as your friend because he can help you a lot... I can assure you that!

Comment: Haha ok. I have asked for advice if he wishes to give any so that I can avoid further errors. I am not very experienced with such forums so I don't know what the viewers expect and what is unnecessary. So I tend to skip over some details sometimes :)